# Saving multiple params in a single array with ajax and rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui

When a card is dragged inside a list, I'm using the`jQueryUI` sortable plugin's `update` callback to send the new position of each card to my controller. This AJAX request posts the `position` attribute of every card in whichever list the dragged card was released in.

```
$(".js-Sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".js-Sortable",
    items: ".js-CardContainer",
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {

            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

            $.ajax({
                url: "/c/sort",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "script",
                data: data,
                success: function(resp){
                    console.log('Yay');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This sends params which look something like this

```
Parameters: {"card"=>["39", "2", "1", "6", "40", "5", "18", "3", "16", "7", "17", "8", "15", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "4"]}
```

I'm then updating each affected card's `position` attribute in my controller action like this:

```
def sort
    params[:card].each_with_index do |id, index|
        card = Card.find(id)
        card.update_attribute(:position, index) if card
    end

    head :ok
end
```

The view looks like this:

```
<ul class="js-CardsContainer js-Sortable">
  <% list.cards.order(:position).where(archived: false).each do |card| %>
    <li class="js-CardContainer" id="card-<%= card.id %>">
      <%= link_to card, class: 'js-Card', :data => { :id => card.id }, remote: true do %>
        <span><%= card.title %></span>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This is all working so far. The problem is, cards can be moved across different lists. So, I need to somehow get the `id` of whichever list the dragged card was released in and post that with the AJAX request too.

I can get the `list_id` as a variable, but how can I add this `list_id` to the array in the AJAX request?

Comment: can you expose DOM?

Comment: i mean show your view

Comment: you can pass list_id in `data` hash

Comment: I was thinking that was possible, but it's the syntax I'm having trouble with. I'm not good with JS, can you explain how to go about passing it in the hash please?

Comment: just build hash in data attribute and pass it

Comment: I can add the list_id as a data attribute and get it as a JS variable, but I don't know how to pass it as a param in the AJAX request alongside the other card IDs. I don't understand the syntax. Can you show me please?

Comment: will discuss it late i am busy now i will surly try to resolve your issue

Comment: @colmtuite did you figure it out?  Passing along your list_id variable is as easy as making another key value pair and passing it along in your data variable.

Comment: `<%= link_to card, class: 'js-Card', :data => { :id => card.id,list_id:list.id }, remote: true do %>
        <span><%= card.title %></span>
      <% end %>` try this and let me

Comment: @kparekh01 I haven't figured it out. I guess it's pretty simple but I have no idea what I'm doing. I have no idea how to structure it or how to pass another key value. Any chance you could show me in the answers?

Comment: Hey Colm, could you throw up a jsfiddle with an example? Things like this usually have source data in the event so might be worth looking there.

Comment: @colmtuite do you need this kind functionality with rails support https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists?

Comment: @colmtuite https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aBsUkJMbmE
 try this railscast

Comment: @uzaif Yes I need functionality exactly like that railscast. I have it working that far, except now I also need to allow cards to move between different lists, so I need to pass the relevant list ID in my AJAX request and I can't figure out the syntax for that. I have the list ID as a variable, but I don't know how to write the jQuery to pass it, or the rails to update it.

Comment: can you show me what inside data attribute? so we can append list there

Comment: Imagine we have var ListID = $(this).parent().data('id');

Comment: So now, I need to add that ListID into the array in the AJAX request somehow and send it to the rails controller and add it to the logic there that updates the attributes of the cards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148726/discussion-between-uzaif-and-colmtuite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your question, you are getting `cards_id` and you want to pass `list_id` along with it

in your DOM you need to add list_id first

```
<%= link_to card, class: 'js-Card', :data => { :id => card.id }, remote: true,"data-list-id":list.id do %>
        <span><%= card.title %></span> <% end %>
```

now you need to fetch this list id in the event handler and combine it with your `cards_id` params

```
$(".js-Sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".js-Sortable",
    items: ".js-CardContainer",
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
            var data = {}
            var data['cards_id'] = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            var data['list_id'] = $(this).attr("data-list-id")
            $.ajax({
                url: "/c/sort",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "script",
                data: data,
                success: function(resp){
                    console.log('Yay');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

in your controller sort action, you need to follow this code

```
params[:card].each_with_index do |id, index, list_id| 
card = Card.find(id) 
card.update(:position => index, 
:list_id => params[:ListId]) 
end
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was late to respond.  To build on @uzaif's answer you can also set key value pairs inside of the data hash itself like so:

```
 var data = {$(this).sortable('serialize'), list_id: $(this).attr("data-list-id")}
```

Like @uzaif said, make sure to adjust your controller to accept the list_id in the parameters hash.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the previous comment, at least one of the objects sent on an event like sorting (and in other jquery UI events like draggable) will usually contain a reference to the previous element.

In this case, the `ui` object contains a sender array which will include a reference at index 0 to the most recent sender: `ui.sender[0]`

I've given an example here of how this could be used in your case:

http://jsfiddle.net/6npx24uf/

Comment: Thanks Mick. I was actually having trouble with combing that variable with the other data in my AJAX request, then passing that data in my rails controller action. I already had the variable I needed. Thanks for your pointer though, I can use that event data for something else.